# Using mergesort with presorted intervals

Tags: c, algorithm, sorting, mergesort

I am trying to prevent any unnecessary recursive calls into mergesort since my array is presorted by parts for example:

```
22, 233, 445, 1055, 1, 14, 94, 74545, 75, 134, 323, 9090, 2, 43, 6342, 323452
```

I am using the generic mergesort implementation

```
void merge(int a[], int low, int mid, int high)
{
    int b[10000];
    int i = low, j = mid + 1, k = 0;

    while (i <= mid && j <= high) {
        if (a[i] <= a[j])
            b[k++] = a[i++];
        else
            b[k++] = a[j++];
    }
    while (i <= mid)
        b[k++] = a[i++];

    while (j <= high)
        b[k++] = a[j++];

    k--;
    while (k >= 0) {
        a[low + k] = b[k];
        k--;
    }
}

void mergesort(int a[], int low, int high)
{
    if (low < high) {
        int m = (high + low)/2;
        mergesort(a, low, m);
        mergesort(a, m + 1, high);
        merge(a, low, m, high);
    }
}
```

If my program knows that every 4 elements is already sorted how can I modify mergesort to *start* merging from sorted groups of 4 instead of breaking the array down to the single element parts and then starting the merge?

Example:

```
22,233,445,1055     1,14,94,74545,     75,134,323,9090     2,43,6342,323452
      \                  /                    \                   /
       \                /                      \                 /
   1,14,22,94,233,445,1055,74545        2,43,75,134,323,6342,9090,323452
              \                                           /
               \                                         /
        1,2,14,22,43,75,94,134,233,323,445,1055,6342,9090,74545,323452
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you implemented is [Top-down mergesort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort#Top-down_implementation), which means to split the array into two parts, sort each, and merge them together. This is done recursively. The problem of it is, assuming the array has 12 elements, then it would split the array into 2 6-element arrays, that would take no advantage of the fact that every 4 elements are already sorted.

You should instead use [Bottom-up mergesort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort#Bottom-up_implementation), that is, split the array into subarrays, each of the subarrays have 4 elements. Since each of them are already sorted, merge every two subarrays into 8-element subarrays, and then merge every two 8-element subarrays into 16-element subarrays, and so on. The code of sorting N-element array is like this:

```
for (int sz = 1; sz < N; sz = sz+sz)
    for (int lo = 0; lo < N-sz; lo += sz+sz)
        merge(a, lo, lo+sz-1, min(lo+sz+sz-1, N-1));
```

Since you already know that every 4 elements are sorted, you can start with `sz` being `4`, which takes full advantage of the knowledge.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help and explanation!  It is now calling merge 3 times instead of 15.  Great improvement.

Comment: One more option - natural merge sort, which finds already sorted data chunks: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort#Natural_merge_sort